# python - URL listener for request submission

Tags: python

What in python can do this? Listener?? not sure what to use

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

- Website1: Generates a code and loads website2 URL :https://website2.com/?code=123423439934&state=619
- On website2 how do I using python listen/watch for this URL submission and capture this request specifically the code?

any help would be appreicated.

Comment: Flask is the most common solution for running Python to process web requests.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a proper Webframework, but if this is the only task the site should do, a simple [Python Web Server](https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/) could do the work:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        query_components = parse_qs(urlparse(self.path).query)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % query_components['code'], "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

Using `urlparse`, you can extract the query parameters from the url, `query_components['code']` in this example.